# How to run Beego binary with production mode in https?

Tags: go, beego

I have my Go app running in https mode. I am using the Beego framework. My app.conf looks like :

```
appname = myproject
httpsport = 10555
httpport = 8082
runmode = prod
EnableHTTP = false
EnableHTTPS = true
HTTPSCertFile = server.crt
HTTPSKeyFile = server.key
copyrequestbody = true
```

when I run it locally it works perfectly fine, GoLang server runs on 10555 with https. But when I build the binary and try to run that on another server, it tries to run on http port 8082 only.

Answer (score 0):

i think what that mean httpport is a port in server/local server, different about what http or https needed.

you can using split method for that env such as a development.conf (`httpport=8082`) for env staging server and production.conf (`httpport=10555`) for env production server and then you can replace the env to app.conf when you deploy

Answer (score 0):

```
I used it like this :
----app.config
{
appname = firstapp
# httpport = 8080
runmode = dev //when in test comment this line
#runmode = test //when in test uncomment this line
autorender = false
copyrequestbody = true
EnableDocs = true
[dev]
httpport = 8080
# [prod]
# httpport = 8088
[test]
httpport = 8888
}
-----main.go
func init() {

// 1 - Enable debug
orm.Debug = false

// 2 - Register object with Beego ORM
orm.RegisterModel(new(models.User), new(models.Role), new(models.Function), new(models.Role_function))
//orm.RegisterModel(new(models.User), new(models.Role))

if beego.BConfig.RunMode == "dev" {
    // 3 - Fetch database properties stored as YAML, decode secrets
    connStr, err := util.FetchYAMLDEV()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    // 4 - Register posgres driver and db
    orm.RegisterDriver("postgres", orm.DRPostgres)
    orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "postgres", connStr)

    // 5 - Create and load DB with sample data, can comment after initial load
    models.CreateDb()
    models.LoadDb()
}

if beego.BConfig.RunMode == "test" {
    // 3 - Fetch database properties stored as YAML, decode secrets
    fmt.Println("in test runmofe")
    connStr, err := util.FetchYAMLTEST()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    // 4 - Register posgres driver and db
    orm.RegisterDriver("postgres", orm.DRPostgres)
    orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "postgres", connStr)

    // 5 - Create and load DB with sample data, can comment after initial load
    models.CreateDb()
    models.LoadDb()
}
}


----util.FetchYAML.go

package util

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "log"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func goDotEnvVariable(key string) string {
// load .env file
err := godotenv.Load(".env")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error loading .env file")
}
return os.Getenv(key)
}

func FetchYAMLDEV() (string, error) {
user := goDotEnvVariable("user_dev")
dbname := goDotEnvVariable("dbname_dev")
password := goDotEnvVariable("password_dev")
host := goDotEnvVariable("host_dev")
port := goDotEnvVariable("port_dev")

return fmt.Sprintf("user=%s dbname=%s password=%s host=%s port=%s sslmode=disable",
    user, dbname, password, host, port), nil
}

func FetchYAMLTEST() (string, error) {

user := goDotEnvVariable("user")
dbname := goDotEnvVariable("dbname")
password := goDotEnvVariable("password")
host := goDotEnvVariable("host")
port := goDotEnvVariable("port")

return fmt.Sprintf("user=%s dbname=%s password=%s host=%s port=%s sslmode=disable",
    user, dbname, password, host, port), nil
}

----.env 
ACCESS_SECRET = vjhbjhjh
user = postgres
dbname = golang
password = password
port = 5432
host = localhost
sslmode = disable

user_dev = devuser
dbname_dev = defdbname
password_dev = devpass
port_dev = 5432
host_dev = devhost
sslmode_dev = disable

user_test = testuser
dbname_test = testdbname
password_test = testpass
port_test = 5432
host_test = testhost
sslmode_test = disable
```